# How to work with many-to-many relation and have direct access to middle table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have 3 tables and many to many relation -- say, **Authors**, **Books**, and **BookAuthors**.

When I update entity framework edmx file (update from database) and select all 3 tables, in effect I will get 2 tables in EF, not 3. **BookAuthors** will be hidden. It is a problem for me, because sometimes all I have is `book_id` and list of `author_id`. In such case I would like to save those values directly in the middle class.

When I try to "cheat", and I update (to EF) first **Books** and **Authors**, and in second update **BookAuthors** (or vice versa) I will get 3 tables in edmx, but I also will get an error while compiling:

> Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines ....  Two entities with
>   possibly different keys are mapped to the same row.  Ensure these two
>   mapping fragments map both ends of the AssociationSet to the
>   corresponding columns.

So how to have many-to-many relation and at the same time have a direct access to middle table?

Comment: How exactly do you "cheat"? Do you create the three tables seperately and add many-to-one relationships between Books and BookAuthors and Authors and BookAuthors? Could you describe this process a bit more?

Comment: @Jim, the tables are already in database. I "cheat" by not updating model in one step, but two steps -- with first update I select (for update) table Books and Authors, and then I perform second update from database and in this step I select BookAuthors table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible when you are using database first approach without modifying the middle table. If you choose to apply Model First approach, just instead of adding many to many relationships, create the middle entity in the model and use one to many relationships.

If you change the database and another column to middle table in a way that middle table does not only include foreign keys, it will also work properly.

I also wonder why you need to access middle table as an entity.

Comment: It is quite simple -- sometimes all I know is bunch of id's of Authors and Books, nothing more. So I would like to update for example some authors for books, without any extra trip to database, the key is to use middle table directly. After all it holds the relations between those two tables (Books, Authors). Let's say you found out, that Book 5 has actually two Authors 2 and 3. How do you update your data without access to middle table?

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand why you need direct access to the middle table.  But just add a dummy boolean field to the table (which will never get used), and EF will stop auto-hiding it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you are trying to do (and where you run into a problem) is take the `book_id` of an existing book, and a list of `author_id`s of authors you'd like to add to the book.

In this case, just pull all the authors from the authors table, and pull the book from the books table, and for each author, do `Book.Authors.Add(author);`.

Comment: "Just pull ...", those pulls don't come for free. With direct access middle table, and being able to store id's directly, I don't pull anything, I push (store) was is needed. And that's why I would like to have access to it.